# react-router 3.x: onEnter being fired when location changes within already entered Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

I have a `Route` component that has an `onEnter` event like so:

`<Route path="users/:accountId(/:projectToView)(/:photoIdentifier)(/:photoTitle)" component={Profile} onEnter={scrollToTop}/>`

I have a function called `scrollToTop` which simply scrolls to the top of the page when a `Route` is entered.

I notice that when I navigate to `/users/:someAccountId`, the `Profile` component loads as expected, and the onEnter function (`scrollToTop`) gets fired as expected.

What I never expected is that even when I navigate deeper into this `Route`, the `onEnter` event gets fired again for every new segment entered of the `Route`.

For example if I am currently sitting in `/users/:someAccountId` and I click a link that takes me to `/users/:someAccountId/:projectToView`, the `onEnter` event gets fired even though I already entered the route?

Is this intended behaviour for this event and is there any way to only have onEnter fired when that certain path gets entered, not for every new routeParam entered within that path?

Comment: It likely gets fired each time because the data in the url changes, so each level you go a new piece of data is added which triggers the onEnter. It looks like you need to implement child routes or nested routing and only apply the onEnter to whatever child routes you want or just the parent if that's what you want.

Comment: @floor I don't understand how I could apply this design with child routes. For example I don't think I could do something like: `<Route path="pros/:accountId" component={Profile> <Route path=(/:projectToView)/> </Route>`. Can I have a 'componentless' child route that just defines a routeParam? Or would I put `component={Profile}` on both the parent and the child route?

Comment: you would likely have the user/:accountId as 1 route then build on that URL with /project/:projectId etc...  https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/04-nested-routes

Comment: @floor That example shows sibling routes. I guess what I need to figure out is how to do multi-nested optional child routes...or something like that? lol

Comment: if you post more code and a detailed explanation of what you are trying to do I can try and help you through it.

Comment: @floor this nested structure does not Route right and does not maintain the mounted component when I try and enter any of the child routes.  `<Route path="pros/:accountId" component={Profile} onEnter={scrollToTop}>
            <Route path="(/:companyName)">
                <Route path="(/:view)">
                    <Route path="(/:projectToView)">
                        <Route path="(/:photoIdentifier)"/>
                    </Route>
                </Route>
            </Route>
        </Route>`

Comment: its hard for me to see what you are doing without you posting your code. But another thing you could do is in your scrollToTop function you can check the url and if it matches the url you want to execute on then do so if not then just do nothing

Comment: @floor I like that approach. But instead of having a bunch of the same `onEnter` functions in my `Route` components. I am wondering if I can access the location/url data through the `Router` component's `onUpdate` function? The docs says it has no parameters so I don't think I can access state or anything like that, like I could in the `Route`'s `onEnter`.

Comment: I don't know the react router api off the top of my head, but make sure the URL has resolved before looking for it. And you will always have access to the window.location to get the URL, but the router may provide the url in its api. You will have to review the docs.